# paginate nested resource with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

Sup! I have

```
@comment = @photo.comments.create(...)
```

And I need to paginate this comments somehow, in the view:

```
- @photo.comments.each do |comment|
  ...
```

But I'm stucked, so help me please.

Do I need define `@comments` to add pagination?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya I think we need to define @comments.

In controller -

```
@comments = @photo.comments.page(params[:page])
```

In view -

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<%= comment.attribute_name %>
<% end %>
<%= paginate @comments %>
```

I tried this and it worked.